# Any better way to create login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js . This is my first basic step. I have created simple login page for accessing. The problem what I am facing is , when I click on the `login()`button, **form()** is not getting submitted and it shows, invalid username and password. I just searched in some other blog also. But I din't understood properly.

Below there is my code :

HTML :

```
<div class="package" ng-controller="credientials">
    <form ng-submit="loginform()"  class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <label form="emailinput">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="username">
      <label form="pwdinput">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="password">
    <div>
      <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="">Login</button>
    </div><br/>
      <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
    </form>
```

Angular JS :

```
var app = angular.module('logapp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/login',{
                    templateUrl : "login.html",
                    controller : "loginctrl"
                })
                .when('/home',{
                    templateUrl : "home.html",
                    controller : "homectrl"
                });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login'});
        });

 app.controller('credientials',['$scope','$route','$http','$window',function($scope,$route,$http,$window){
   $scope.templates =
                [
                    { url: 'login.html' },
                    { url: 'practice.html'}
                ];
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
                    $scope.loginform = function (username, password) {
                if ( username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {
                    authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
                    $scope.user = username;
                } else {
                    $scope.error = "Invalid username and password";
                };
              };
      app.factory('authentication', function() {
                return {
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null
              }
        });

    }]);
```

Comment: use $scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === '1234'

Comment: @VolkanAkınPaşa . I just tried your code , but i got **authentication** is undefined.

Comment: I pass that authentication through the function . but still i got the error

Comment: I have made a sample added the URL. Please check it. It works

Comment: @VolkanAkınPaşa. Thanks . My code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject the factory 'authentication' into your controller.

```
app.controller('credientials',['$scope','$route','$http','$window',function($scope,$route,$http,$window,authentication){
```

and you must use $scope for your username and password

```
 $scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === '1234'
```

and then you will see your variable isAuthenticated in factory will be true

I have changed your code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xqgWhle09fAb5enKaIyv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put username and password on the scope.
Maybe this will work better:

```
$scope.username = "";
$scope.password = "";
$scope.loginform = function () {
if ( $scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === '1234') {
```

You should really consider this tutorial
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial